# SQL SERVER: String or binary data would be truncated. nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert into the following table:

[image]

but for some reason I cannot insert more than 250 characters into slabel1 field, even though it's size it's 500. Every time this happens I receive the following error:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

I do not understand why.

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, but perhaps utf-8 require 2 bytes / character?

Comment: How did you obtain the information in the question? What is this `length`? Is it the number from when you declared the table, or is it the length in bytes?

Comment: @jarlh you are right that each character takes 2 bytes rather than 1 but specifying 500 for nvarchar should still allow 500 characters the cost would be 1000 bytes. 
Question is, is the screenshot above the table design or a result of some query?

Comment: I obtained that table is sql server 2008 by selecting the table name with mouse cursor and pressing ALT + F1. I was told that I can find  each column type and length like this

Answer (score 10):

Your results show the length in bytes of the column, not how many characters it can store. The column you are using is an nvarchar column, and so a character will take up 2 bytes instead of 1, so in your case (500 / 2) = 250 characters max.

This will show you the difference, we have two columns, each which can hold 50 characters, but the length of the nvarchar column is 100

```
CREATE TABLE [#text]
(
  [Text] VARCHAR(50),
  [NText] NVARCHAR(50)
)

SELECT COL_LENGTH( 'tempdb..#Text' , 'Text' ) [Varchar_Length],
       COL_LENGTH( 'tempdb..#Text' , 'NText' ) [NVarchar_Length]


DROP TABLE [#text]
```

The results are:

```
Varchar_Length | NVarchar_Length
50             | 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's `NVARCHAR`

[nchar and nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql)

> **nchar [ ( n ) ]**
>
> Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string
>   length and must be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is
>   two times n bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte
>   characters, the storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the
>   string, the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value
>   specified for n. The ISO synonyms for nchar are national char and
>   national character..
>
> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> Variable-length Unicode string data. n
>   defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max
>   indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The
>   storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered
>   + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

Try this one to see the differences

```
DECLARE @text1 NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @text2 VARCHAR(200)

SET @text1 = 'aaaaaaaa'
SET @text2 = 'aaaaaaaa'

SELECT LEN(@text1), DATALENGTH(@text1)

SELECT LEN(@text2), DATALENGTH(@text2)
```

Comment: `nvarchar(200)` means 200 characters (or Unicode UCS-2 codes), not 200 bytes. The usage of the word `bytes` in the documentation specifically relates to `nvarchar(max)`. **n defines the string length**